# Testing Presenter with DisposableObserver

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, clean-architecture

I'm developing an Android application, trying to follow Clean Architecture / MVP guidelines.

I'm currently wiriting Unit Tests for my presenters, but I'm stuck with the call to the Interactor/UseCase, that takes a DisposableObserver as a parameter.

What I would like to test is that the correct behavior is called when the interactor invokes OnNext or OnError for example (hide/show loading indicator...).

I don't know how to 'mock' the behavior of the Observable in my use Case, as it is built when the execute() method is called, using a protected method.

Below are some portions of code:

#### Presenter

```
@ConfigPersistent
public class ContentPresenter extends BasePresenter<ContentContract.View> implements ContentContract.Presenter {

    @Inject
    GetContent mGetContentUseCase;

    @Inject
    ContentViewModelMapper mContentViewModelMapper;

    @Inject
    public ContentPresenter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchContent(long contentId) {
        getMvpView().showProgress();
        mGetContentUseCase.execute(contentId, new ContentObserver());
    }

    private final class ContentObserver extends DisposableObserver<Content> {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Content content) {
            getMvpView().hideProgress();
            getMvpView().showContentInfo(mContentViewModelMapper.map2(content));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            getMvpView().hideProgress();
            Timber.e(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            getMvpView().hideProgress();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Interactor/UseCase

```
public class GetContent extends UseCaseObservableWithParameter<Long, Content, Repository> {

    @Inject
    public GetContent(Repository repository,
                         @Named("Thread") Scheduler threadScheduler,
                         @Named("PostExecution") Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
        super(repository, threadScheduler, postExecutionScheduler);
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable<Content> buildObservable(Long id) {
        return repository.getContentById(id);
    }
}
```

#### BaseUseCase

```
public abstract class UseCaseObservableWithParameter<REQUEST_DATA, RESPONSE_DATA, REPOSITORY> extends UseCase<Observable<RESPONSE_DATA>, REQUEST_DATA, REPOSITORY> {

    public UseCaseObservableWithParameter(REPOSITORY repository, Scheduler threadScheduler, Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
        super(repository, threadScheduler, postExecutionScheduler);
    }

    protected abstract Observable<RESPONSE_DATA> buildObservable(REQUEST_DATA requestData);

    public void execute(REQUEST_DATA requestData, DisposableObserver<RESPONSE_DATA> useCaseSubscriber) {
        this.disposable.clear();
        this.disposable.add(
                this.buildObservable(requestData)
                        .subscribeOn(threadScheduler)
                        .observeOn(postExecutionScheduler)
                        .subscribeWith(useCaseSubscriber)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, this is what I came up with:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testShowContents() {
    doAnswer((i) -> {
        // Do stuff with i.getArguments() here
        DisposableObserver<Content> d = i.getArgument(1);
        Observable.just(mock(Content.class)).subscribeWith(d);
        return null;
    })
            .when(mGetContentUseCase)
            .execute(eq(AppTestData.TEST_LONG_ID_1), any(DisposableObserver.class));

    contentPresenter.fetchContent(AppTestData.TEST_LONG_ID_1);

    Mockito.verify(view, Mockito.times(1)).showContentInfo(Mockito.any());

    InOrder orderVerifier = Mockito.inOrder(view);
    orderVerifier.verify(view).showProgress();
    orderVerifier.verify(view).hideProgress();
    orderVerifier.verify(view).showContentInfo(any());
}

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testShowContentsError() {
    doAnswer((i) -> {
        // Do stuff with i.getArguments() here
        DisposableObserver<Content> d = i.getArgument(1);
        Observable.<Content>error(new Throwable()).subscribeWith(d);
        return null;
    })
            .when(mGetContentUseCase)
            .execute(eq(AppTestData.TEST_LONG_ID_1), any(DisposableObserver.class));

    contentPresenter.fetchContent(AppTestData.TEST_LONG_ID_1);

    Mockito.verify(view, Mockito.times(1)).showErrorMessage(Mockito.any());

    InOrder orderVerifier = Mockito.inOrder(view);
    orderVerifier.verify(view).showProgress();
    orderVerifier.verify(view).hideProgress();
    orderVerifier.verify(view).showErrorMessage(any());
}
```